# How can I align the first line of a description list with the rest in LyX?

Tags: lyx, indentation, description

I'm new to LyX. How can I achieve the list style reflected in the second picture?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The vertical red line show that "A. ..."  is a nested list  in another list. Probably is the `lyxlist` environment  (list button = Alt+P L) in a `description` list (description button = Alt+P D) but without code nor  the document class is hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** The `Description` in the standard `article` class typesets as you desire, but the typesetting changes according to document class.
So: Change your document class to the standard article, or redefine how the `description` environment is typeset.

**Original:**
If you are working in the standard `article` document class, then the `Enumerate` environment typesets as you want.

So: Change the environment of your list from `Description` (?) to `Enumerate`.

If you want the items labeled with something custom, then go `Insert > Custom Item` when on the line you want to change the label of and then write your desired label in the resulting box. In the screenshot, I didn't bold the text, but bolding it works, too.

[image]